# How to wait until async function finished before executing other lines of code

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I have a function which uploading image. I put the code in some service file, and invoke it in another component which call that service. I want to execute another lines of code in the component who call the service just after the uploading progress is success.

I have read another similar question about this. But, I can't capture the answer clearly, because in another question the async function and a function after lies in same file. I have some clue `Promise` and `Observable`. but I am not understand well how to use it properly

Here is the service I have:

```
public changeImage = (e: any, prevImage: string, filePath: string) => {
    const file  = e.target.files[0];
    const ref   = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    const task  = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      finalize(() => console.log(`Finished`) )
    ).subscribe();
}
```

and here is the component that call the service:

```
public uploadImage = async (e: any) => {
    this.uploading        = true;
    await this.imageStorage.changeImage(e, this.admin.adminImage, `admin/${e.target.files[0].name}`);
    /* I want to execute code here after upload is success */
    this.uploading = false; /* executed after upload finished */
}
```

How can i achieved that?

Comment: Don't subscribe in the service. Return the observable, and let the component subscribe. Apparently you alread know how to print "finished" when the upload is finished, so you should be able to set uploading to false.

Comment: after playing around, it works mate. Thank @JBNizet